# Is UNION faster than running separate queries?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance, union

I have 7 tables that I could UNION on (wwith a limit of 30)

OR

should I do 7 separate queries (with a limit of 30) and trace through them using PHP.

Which why is faster? More optimal?  In the second way I would have to trace through part of the 7 queries simulataneously and find the top 30 I need.

Comment: More details would be helpful. I mean, theoretically UNION would be faster than sending multiple queries, but only if UNION is actually appropriate in this context. And it usually isn't :/

Comment: I thinks this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260038/mysql-performance-multiple-queries-or-one-inefficient-query

Comment: Keep in mind that `UNION` does an implicit distinct. use `UNION ALL` if the distinct is not neccessary.

Comment: JOIN is faster than separate queries, theory says that much.  Not sure about UNION.  But testing your queries is the best way, regardless of what theory says.

Comment: Trying to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207336/complex-sql-maybe-outer-joins

Comment: Presumably your 'front end' code would have to do extra work to handle two resultsets rather than one. I think for a meaningful comparison, your performance testing should include this extra work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is your needs?

As @chris wrote before, this may help you:
[Complex SQL (Maybe Outer Joins)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207336/complex-sql-maybe-outer-joins)

```
select * from (select ... from ... order ... limit 10 )
union all
select * from (select ... from ... order ... limit 10)
 order by ... limit 10
```

As I know (checked on DB with 50 million rows) - its fater than not using the devired queries.

Answer (score 3):

Before making decisions you need at least to run both kinds of queries with MySql's EXPLAIN and analyze results. Something like this:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM t1
    UNION ALL
       SELECT f1, f2, f3 FROM t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

depends if each query produce unique results using UNION ALL is better you save server trips, and you can sort the result after the union is performed. e.g

```
 select column1 alias1, column2 alias2, from table x where ... 
  UNION ALL
  select column3 alias1, column2 alias2 from table y where ...
  ...
  order by 1
```

Sorry by my English